# creating Diagnostic area through feature receiver

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a diagnostic area for logging needs of my application through feature receiver.  I have 2 ways to do this.  Create a farm feature and have the code in feature_activated and deactivated.
Second way is have a site collection scoped feature and have the code in feature_installed and uninstalled

My question is when this the feature is activated on one of the web front end servers, is it required to be activated on other WFE's also?  I was thinking if it is activated in one WFE, it should suffice as it is farm configuration and need not be activated on each WFE.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Feature activation affects the feature object in the SharePoint database; config or content, depending on you feature scope. It doesn't matter against what server in the farm you performed it. After the feature was activated, the next feature status check performed on other server in the farm will yield the active status. Also, your feature receiver will be called just once; not on every WFE.